# Globally Override Linq to SQL to save object strings as Empty Strings instead of NULL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

When saving an object that has a string property that hasn't been explicitly set to an empty string, LINQ to SQL will try to insert this record with a NULL value.

I would AGREE this is how it should work. However for a particular DB I'm writing to I'd like to globally override this functionality to always save an empty string.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```cs
public partial class NorthwindDataContext
{
    public override void SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
    {
        this.EmptyNullProperties();

        base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
    }

    private void EmptyNullProperties()
    {
        var propertiesToEmpty =
            from entity in this.GetChangeSet().Inserts
            from property in entity.GetType().GetProperties()
            where property.CanRead && property.CanWrite
            where property.PropertyType == typeof(string)
            where property.GetValue(entity) == null
            select new { entity, property };

        foreach (var pair in propertiesToEmpty)
        {
            pair.property.SetValue(pair.entity, string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @aherrick: did you know you can add support for DataAnnotations and Validation Application block by using the metadata (attributes) that LINQ to SQL places on your entities (such as max length and not null constraints)? [Here's more info](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=64).